# Sending mail by Unauthorised sender in Google AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email, sendmail

I've got a Google AppEngine Python application connected with **my domain**.
I want to be able to send emails from any email, like: *mailname@**mydomain.com***
So I use sendmail() and set mailobject.sender = "sender@mydomain.com", but it does not work.
Also I made a receive function, but I don't want to receive mails here, so I just made

```
def receive(self, mail):
    pass
```

In Google Documentation https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail :

- Any valid email receiving address for the app (such as
  xxx@APP-ID.appspotmail.com).
- Any valid email receiving address of a
  domain account, such as support@example.com. Domain accounts are
  accounts outside of the Google domain with email addresses that do
  not end in @gmail.com or @APP-ID.appspotmail.com.

What should I add to the application in order to be able to send mails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/emailmessagefields

> **sender**
>
> The email address of the sender, the From address. The sender
>   address must be one of the following types:
>
> - The address of a registered administrator for the application. You can add
>     administrators to an application using the Administration Console.
> - The address of the user for the current request signed in with a Google
>     Account. You can determine the current user's email address with the
>     Users API. The user's account must be a Gmail account, or be on a
>     domain managed by Google Apps.
> - Any valid email receiving address for the app (such as xxx@APP-ID.appspotmail.com).

This means that there is no documented way to send from *@example.org. I thought that there was a way if your @example.org was a google apps domain but I cannot find any docs on that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming mydomain.com is registered as a Google Domain Account, try adding sender@mydomain.com with the role 'Developer' in the Permissions section of the App Engine Admin Console: https://appengine.google.com/permissions?&app_id=s~yourapp (replace yourapp with your app's ID)

For more information see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail

Comment: but name for sender generates automatically,
so there is no way to do it without adding it in the Permissions section?

Comment: @Sindbag If you add you sender@mydomain.com to the Permissions section then the example in the documentation will work.

Comment: the problem is that it is just an example, there are way more different names

Comment: I don't follow, when you say there are way more different names, you mean you want to send from a lot of different email addresses? The reason Google require you to whitelist sender addresses like this is to make it harder for someone to create an AppEngine app to send spam.

Comment: I know, but for any @ app-id.appspotmail.com it works, but for @ mydomain.com it does not